# How to transfer files from windows to Linux

Tags: 12.04

I have a computer on which both Linux and windows are present.
I installed Linux because the computer wasn't working on windows. 
However, when I installed Linux none of the files were transferred from windows to Linux although during installation it suggested otherwise. 
So, I want to know how to transfer the files from windows to Linux.

Comment: Is there a drive in windows "my computer"?

Comment: show us `sudo fdisk -l` output, in an update to the question.

Comment: No I mean the problem with my comp is that there is some error because of which it doesn't work  on windows when I try to start it with windows it keeps restarting and it doesn't even open till the desktop which is why I installed Linux on it

Comment: It would be extremely easy to answer your question if you would answer j0h's.

Comment: I am a kid so pardon me for asking this:-how do I get access to the sudo fdisk?

Comment: Use the `terminal` command.  You can get to it by typing `term` in Ubuntu's launch button.

Answer (score 0):

Your windows files will be on a separate drive or partition.

You should see this drive/partition under the device section of your file browser.  Clicking on it from there should either open it or mount it and open it.

If for some reason you don't see it there automatically, you can check your connected drives and partitions by running applications such as `gnome-disk-utility`.

From the Ubuntu Launch button type `disk` in the search field.  The left panel will display all your connected drives.  You can select a drive by clicking on it.  Then on the right you'll see the GUI of the partitions.  You can select the desired partition.  Once selected (mouse clicked) you'll have an option to mount it by clicking the play button (it looks like a triangle).  Once mounted you'll see it listed in your file browser.

You can unmount it by clicking on the stop (square associated with it).